# AppleScript to open "Open Recent" file

Tags: applescript

Is it possible to open a recent file with an AppleScript?
I tried the following script but it doesn't work.

```
on run
    try
        tell application "System Events"
            set theApp to (get name of first process whose frontmost is true)
            click menu bar item "Archivio" of menu bar 1 of process theApp
            click menu item "Apri recente" of menu "Archivio" of menu bar item "Archivio" of menu bar 1 of process theApp
            click menu item " test" of menu "Apri recente" of menu item "Apri recente" of menu "Archivio" of menu bar item "Archivio" of menu bar 1 of process theApp
        end tell
    end try
end run
```

The error is

> --> error number -1728 from «class menI» " test" of «class menE» "Apri recente" of «class menI» "Apri recente" of «class menE» "Archivio" of «class mbri» "Archivio" of «class mbar» 1 of «class prcs» "AppleScript Editor"

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug when the "**Apri recente**" submenu is open.
But this is not necessary, you can do it in one click.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell (get first process whose frontmost is true)
        click menu item " test" of menu "Apri recente" of menu item "Apri recente" of menu "Archivio" of menu bar item "Archivio" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```